# How to get rid of errors when running find command in Linux?

Tags: linux, find, redhat-enterprise-linux, tcsh

I am using following command to list out 20 large files in a directory. But along with the file listing, it also shows error messages, such as *permission denied*.  I tried adding `2> /dev/null` but it does not seem to like it.

This is the command I'm using

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

May I know how to avoid all the error message and only display the list of files?

Answer (score 3):

In bash, `2> /dev/null` would actually work, as long as you add it as part of the find command itself, i.e., before the pipe.

For example, this will work:

```
find -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

With tcsh, there's no straightforward way to do the same, but [man tcsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) mentions a workaround:

> The shell cannot presently redirect diagnostic output without also redirecting standard output, but '*(command > output-file) >& error-file*' is often an acceptable workaround. Either *output-file* or *error-file* may be '/dev/tty' to send output to the terminal.

For a plain find command, this gives:

```
(find > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null
```

When using pipes, in contrast to bash, you have to place `> /dev/tty` after the last pipe to avoid the *Ambiguous output redirect.* error message.

This will work in tcsh:

```
(find -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 20 > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null
```

Comment: With your suggestion, I am getting following error - Ambiguous output redirect.

Comment: I tried this find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 20 but it is giving out error - Ambiguous output redirect

Comment: I think this is because I am using tcsh and not bash.

Comment: I've installed tcsh and I found a way.

Comment: So to output to a file: `(find -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 20 > file.txt) >& /dev/null`